# Compare two CSV file and update one CSV file based on compared result using Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

I'm new to Python and written this code to compare two CSV file. The idea is:
my 1st CSV file has only one column:

1st CSV

```
    ColA
    ----

     A
     B
     C
```

My 2nd CSV file is like:

```
     Country    ColA  ColB
     -------------------------
      US          A
     Ind          B      
                  C     AU K-
```

What I wanted is, if any record of ColA of 1st CSV file matches with ColA of 2nd CSV file
then, I want to parse ColB's "AU K-" value to get only "AU" and update in the country of the 2nd CSV file. and my output should look like this:

So, my 2nd CSV file/Output file will look like:

```
  Country    ColA  ColB
   ---------------------
   US           A
   Ind          B      
   AU           C
```

The following code is written to find the match: However, I'm not getting the output in the console while testing. The console simply appears and disappears.

How to retain the console so that I can read the matches? Also, how to update the 2nd CSV if the values matched?

Below is my code sample how I' doing this:

```
import pandas
 with open('D:\Project\SourceFile.csv') as f:
r = pandas.read_csv(f)
with open('D:\Project\Searchfile.csv','r') as w:
x = pandas.read_csv(w)

col = w['ColA']
for line in w:
    for col in w:
        for row in r:
            if row in col:
                print(line)
```

Note: I'm using IronPython on VS 2015 with Win7 64Bit. Using IronPython as I would like to integrate few things with .Net code.However, I'm open for any normal/default Python tool.

It looks like IronPython or Python on Windows is somehow not reading CSV file: I referred this (http://pythonhow.com/data-analysis-with-python-pandas/ ) just to test, however, nothing is showing up..Not sure why? Checked environment variables and Python folder, DLLs and Libs are added. What am I doing wrong?
Hope I explained it correctly.

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: You iterate over `w` twice. That shouldn't work. And also your indentation is off.

Comment: How to make this ON? Could you please elaborate the answer? Any solution link would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it can look like with Pandas and Numpy (Pandas 0.15 Python 3)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

w["Country"] = np.where((w["ColA"].isin(r['ColA'].tolist())) & (~ pd.notnull(w["Country"])) ,w["ColB"], w["Country"]) 
# Np.where(condition, if true,if false)
```

It will affect the value of the ColB in w in Country only if the value of ColA in w is also in ColA of r and that there isn't a country entered yet.

Hope it helps

Comment: Could you please elaborate; How this particular line of code works? Or any link that I can refer? Thanks.

Comment: Documentation : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where   I don't see other explanations to give that the comments, sorry